# Encyclopedia of Groups

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, online-resources, reference-works

I was wondering whether or not there was an online encyclopedia of groups--finite or infinite. If there isn't, would you suppose that such a thing would be useful?

Comment: Have you looked at http://hobbes.la.asu.edu/groups/groups.html?

Comment: Groups of order at most 12 are given at http://web.science.mq.edu.au/~chris/groups/appendix.pdf

Comment: The [Atlas of Finite Group Representations](http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/) looks relevant.

Comment: The [GAP system for computational group theory](http://www.gap-system.org/) has a number of [data libraries](http://www.gap-system.org/Datalib/datalib.html), including an interface to the Atlas of Group Representations.  Of course this is more in the way of a downloadable package than an online resource.

Comment: Nobody yet has mentioned [Groupprops, the group properties wiki](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page)

Comment: To expand on hardmath's comment, GAP (and anything that interfaces to GAP e.g. sage) has a SmallGroups library containing every group of order <=2000 except those of order 1024 --- this is over **400 million** groups.  It also has all groups of squarefree order, small cubefree order groups, all $p$-groups of order $\leq p^6$,...  See http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/htm/ref/CHAP048.htm#SECT007  It also has databases of primitive permutation groups, classical groups, finite perfect groups, and more: http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/htm/ref/CHAP048.htm

Comment: @GerryMyerson the link in your comment is now broken.  Could you repost an updated link please?

Comment: @Zero, there are links in two of my comments. It would have been helpful, had you indicated which one was broken. Anyway, the content of the mq.edu.au page is (currently) available at http://www.coopersnotes.net/third_groups.html – scroll down to Appendix A, and click on it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson apologies yes I see you have two separate comments.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may also want to read a nice article of Conway, Dietrich and O'Brien http://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/gnu.pdf

And also the paper of Besche, Eick and O'Brien http://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/2000.pdf which contains a table of the number of groups of order $n < 2001$.

Comment: These papers look very interesting. I'll read them when I get the time.

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: Lance Pollard notes that the links below are broken. Groups of order up to 30 are (currently) available at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_groups and at [http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~atparris/small_groups.html](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Eatparris/small_groups.html)

Groups of order less than 30 are at http://opensourcemath.org/gap/small_groups.html

Also, [http://world.std.com/~jmccarro/math/SmallGroups/SmallGroups.html](http://world.std.com/%7Ejmccarro/math/SmallGroups/SmallGroups.html) goes up to order 32.

Comment: Links are broken.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs, Wolphram|Alpha or Mathematica itself might be helpful. See [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GroupTheory.html) for the computational overview, and [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FiniteGroupData.html) for the data function (open up the "More Information" for the sorts of things you can search.)

Answer (score 1):

Another older reference is Marshall Hall, Jr, and James K. Senior, *The groups of order $2^n\ \ (n < 6)$* (Macmillan, New York,
1964).

Answer (score 0):

For smallish (up to order 500, with gaps for order 256 and 384) finite groups, this website of Tim Dokchitser might be of interest:

[https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/index.html](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/index.html)